# My HD Graphics 4000 is not supporting 3 screens on ubuntu 18 (or 16)

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics

I have a Dell Latitude E5430 latop with the following processor:

```
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3520M CPU @ 2.90GHz
```

according to https://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/latit/dell_latitude_e5430_spec_sheet.pdf, that means that I have the following graphics card:

```
Intel® HD Graphics 4000 for Intel Core i3/i5/i7 3xxxM processors
```

which seems to correspond to this:

```
$ lspci | grep -i graph
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

According to https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000025672/graphics-drivers.html it should support three screens, and I think that the guy that I inherited the computer from at work told me that he had three screens going on windows.  On ubuntu, as soon as I plug anything in to the HDMI jack, the screen connected by VGA one stops working.

Is there any way to fix this?  Is this a limitation of the graphics card, linux, or ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

OK if anybody else has this issue it seems it is a limitation of the graphics card. It's was an ubuntu question, but it turns out it's more of a linux answer.

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/33cc938e65a98f1d29d0a18403dbbee050dcad9a/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/display/intel_fdi.c#L251

it was hitting this line

```
fdi link B uses too many lanes to enable link C
```

and then completely failing, and returning to the previous configuration.

Additionally, I couldn't switch to tty mode using ctrl+alt+f1 because in tty mode, it was always trying to use all my screens and totally failing, instead of just failing and going back to my previous configuration.  To fix this, since I have two external screens, I completely deactivate my internal screen at startup:

```
$ cat /proc/cmdline 
BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-6.6.0-dirty root=/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root ro video=LVDS-1:d
```

So now if I ever want to use my laptop as a laptop I have to restart and change that boot param in grub.

If you do have the same issue as me - 2 external screens that can only work because you have your internal screen turned off, and then you urgently need to switch tty, and it just looks like your screen is frozen, then just unplug one of your two external screens, and your ttys should work.